# differential equation for a subspace (Linear & vector Calculus)

Tags: calculus

I can't seem to work out this question because it's so weird
The set F of all function from R to R is a vector space
given the diffential equation f"(x)+3f'(x)+x^2 f(x) = sin(x) is a subspace of F? Justify your answer

I know that we have to proof that it's non-empty
0. The zero vector has to be in S
1. if u and v are in U, then u+v lies in S
2. by multiplication scalar k(u)

So I tried to solve it but it doesn't make sense & this is my soluiton. If anyone know how to solve it please help me! Anything will help

Check for non-empty
f"(0)+3f'(0)+0^2 f(0)= sin(0)
=0 therefore the set S is non empty

Check A1- closed under addition
=(f+g)" + 3(f+g)'+ x^2 (f+g) = sin (x)
=f" + g" + 3f' + 3g'+ x^2f+ x^2g = sin(x)
= (f"+3f'+ x^2f) + (g" +3g'+x^2g) - sin (x)

I do not know what to do with the constant x^2 and sin(x). I even tried to sub (f+g) into them but it doesn't seem right. Also I tried to sub in real number like 1 and the answer doesn't turn into 0 so does that mean it's not a subspace of F?

Second question:
Use subspace theorem to decide whether the following set is a vector space
The set V of all real polynomials p of degree at most 2 satisfying p(1) = p (2) i.e poly with the same values at x=1 and x=2

0) p(x)=0 therefore V is non-empty
1) let t=p+q; t is a polynomial, and for every x∈R it satisfies t(x)=p(x)+q(x). In particular;
t(1)=p(1)+q(1)
    =p(2)+q(2)
    =t(2)
because p,q∈V therefore V is closed under addition
2)Let p be any polynomial in V, let α be any real number, let q=αp (i.e., q(x)=αp(x) for all x∈R), and show that q∈V.

is the second question look right? please help, thank you!

Comment: The zero vector, $f(x)=0$, is not a solution to the equation, the set of solutions fail the first test of being a subspace.

Comment: maybe you mean to say it as something like an affine space, but I'm not sure what the nomenclature is, so just adding that for others to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a subspace. Note that any vector space of functions contains the $0$ function. And the $0$ function is not a solution of your DE.

There are lots of other ways in which the set of solutions is not a subspace of $F$. For let $y_1$ and $y_2$ be solutions. If the set of solutions was a subspace, then $y_1+y_2$ would be a solution. But if we evaluate the left-hand side at $y_1+y_2$, the result is $2\sin x$, not $\sin x$.

And there are other ways in which the set of solutions is not a subspace of $F$. For if it was a subspace, then if $y$ is in the space, so is $17y$. But if we evaluate the left-hand side at $17y$, we get $17\sin x$, not $\sin x$, so $17y$ is not a solution of the DE.

Comment: so you saying the first question: f"(x)+3f'(x)+x^2 f(x) = sin(x) is not a subspace? that what I thought as well because when I tried to sub in values it doesn't turn to 0 so it's not a subspace. Does it mean it not closed under addition? u+v? also for second question can you check it please. Thank you ^^

Comment: The other question is done a bit awkwardly, but the solution is essentially correct.

Comment: @user68517: If you have a linear **homogeneous** DE, the set of solutions is a subspace of the space of all functions. If you have a linear non-homogeneous DE, the set of solutions is not a subspace of the space of all functions.

Comment: yep, I learn that at uni. So can I conclude for the first question that it's not a subspace because it's not closed under addition? According to subspace theorem: 1/V≠∅. (V is non-empty.)
2/If p,q∈V, then p+q∈V. (V is closed under vector addition.)
3/If p,q∈V and α∈R, then αp∈V. (V is closed under scalar multiplication. For question 2) how can you do it the proper way? because it say it's awkwardly lol since I guess how you would do the question like that, if you got a better way please show me =) thank you very much!!

Comment: Certainly! The first sentence of the answer asserts it is not a subspace. The rest of the answer gives three different ways it fails to be a subspace. One way is enough.

Comment: thank you very much! I didn't see you explain on the top part so yeah cus u edited it. For question 2 what's the best way to solve question 2? the way I solve is ok? you are my life saver ^^

Comment: @genepeer how do you know it's not a 0 vector? f(x)=0 because when I usually test for non-empty (0 vector) I just sub in 0 into the equation to see if it's equal 0 f"(0)+3f'(0)+x^2f(0)=sin(0) everything seem to be equal 0 thought. Then why you say the first test failed? I'm so confused, you mind explain a bit more how you obtain your answer?

Comment: Please remember it is not **values** of the function at a particular place that matter. The only thing that matters is that $\sin x$ is not the **identically** $0$ function. Of course $\sin x$ is $0$ at various places, but that is not relevant.

Comment: Nicolas o so u saying that the function is dependent function instead of linearly independent? because the whole f"(x)+3f'(x)+x^2f(x) equal sin(x) right? The question ask to justify your answer! I understand what you are saying but I need to proof that's not a subspace so yeah. So what's the proper way to say it's not a subspace of function F? Do I just give an example that you show me above and some line saying it's not identically to the right hand side? Can I say that this set of DE is inhomogenous equation? therefore it's cannot be a subspace. Thank you very much for helping!! =)

Comment: xThe simplest thing to write is that (i) The identically $0$ function is an element of any subspace of $F$ and (ii) the identically $0$ function $y()=0$ for all $x$ is not a solution of the DE, since if you put $y\equiv 0$, the left side is identically $0$. But $\sin x$ is not identically $0$.

Comment: Nicolas :O I think I get it now!!!! the right hand side sin(x) only have x but not y so therefore it cannot equal 0 right??? the left hand side have all the y so you can sub y(x)=0 and the whole thing equal 0 but the right is not! OMG THANK GOD! stupid ass question... THANK YOU ^_^